Spamassassin whitelist is not taken into account
I have a postfix / dovecot /roundcube running on a ubuntu 22.04
I have some user which get mail with a false warning on SPAM
=>     [***** SPAM 6.2 *****] xxxx
With a score higher than 4 which is the value I set in the conf.
I have add the mail of the sender in "/usr/share/spamassassin/local.cf"
Quote
shortcircuit USER_IN_WHITELIST       on
shortcircuit USER_IN_DEF_WHITELIST   on
whitelist_from notif-colissimo-laposte.info

reboot the server
But mail from the sender still arrive with a SPAM score higer than 4...
any idea why ?
Thanks

The line prefix is incomplete and the line itself is malformed. When adding addresses and/or domains to safe lists, you need to use whitelist_from_rcvd in the following manner:
whitelist_from_rcvd *@domain

So, for your specific case, it would be:
whitelist_from_rcvd *@notif-colissimo-laposte.info notif-colissimo-laposte.info

The second use of notif-colissimo-laposte.info tells Spamassassin to verify that the domain is found in the receive headers. This reduces the risk of messages getting through with a spoofed address (such as the fake Paypal or Google emails that plague the Internet).

Hello I have perform the change, but it still goes in spam directorry. How can I check the filter is loaded with the right argument? How can I test the spamassassin whitelist (without waiting for an error)
